# creating a value for the css method

Tags: jquery

This doesn't work. I don't understand why this won't work. $tops turns into combined then that value is used to give css top value

```
var $popout = $('.popOut'),
      $currentButton,
      $win = $(window),
      $trigger = $('#leaderBottom a'),
      $closeOut = $('.xOut');





$('#leaderBottom a').on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        $popout.css('display','block');
        $('<div class="overlay"></div>').appendTo('#leaderBottom');

          // find the position of the link according to window
           var $tops = $(this).offset();

          // combined  that nuM plus 50
           var combin = $tops + 50;

            ///adds it all up. and it sends it to combined
           $popout.css("top",combin);

           console.log(combin);



  });
```

Comment: i think you have to say something like `$popout.css("top","12px");`, `px` should be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns an object which contains the co-ordinates. So you would want to do:

```
var combin = $tops.top + 50;
```